Is there an efficient way of storing monotone polygons after dividing the main polygon through diagonals?
(https://i.sstatic.net/rUIgPAlk.png)
I am working on a problem of triangulating a simple polygon(that does not have any of its edges intersecting each other), a step of which involves decomposing the whole polygon into monotone polygons(a polygon that intersects at most two times to a horizontal or vertical line drawn upon it).
My decomposition algorithm works upon the set of edges for the polygon and results in diagonal edges in the format of:
diagonals = [
{'source': {'X': -2.5, 'Y': 7.8}, 'end': {'X': -5.6, 'Y': 13.6}},
{'source': {'X': 8.9, 'Y': 5.5}, 'end': {'X': 8.3, 'Y': 10.9}},
{'source': {'X': -5.5, 'Y': 0.9}, 'end': {'X': -5.6, 'Y': 13.6}},
{'source': {'X': 4.4, 'Y': -3.8}, 'end': {'X': 8.3, 'Y': 10.9}},
{'source': {'X': 4.0, 'Y': 1.9}, 'end': {'X': 1.9, 'Y': -7.7}},
{'source': {'X': 4.4, 'Y': -3.8}, 'end': {'X': 4.0, 'Y': 1.9}}
] 


The format of the edges(with the image's test case) is as follows:
edges = 
[
[{'X': -6.8, 'Y': 4.1}, {'X': -9.1, 'Y': 1.6}], [{'X': -9.1, 'Y': 1.6}, {'X': -8.7, 'Y': -3.9}], [{'X': -8.7, 'Y': -3.9}, {'X': -5.5, 'Y': 0.9}], [{'X': -5.5, 'Y': 0.9}, {'X': -6.4, 'Y': -6.5}], [{'X': -6.4, 'Y': -6.5}, {'X': -3.4, 'Y': -11.7}], [{'X': -3.4, 'Y': -11.7}, {'X': -2.5, 'Y': 7.8}], [{'X': -2.5, 'Y': 7.8}, {'X': 1.9, 'Y': -7.7}], [{'X': 1.9, 'Y': -7.7}, {'X': 4.4, 'Y': -3.8}], [{'X': 4.4, 'Y': -3.8}, {'X': 6.7, 'Y': -11.7}], [{'X': 6.7, 'Y': -11.7}, {'X': 8.9, 'Y': 5.5}], [{'X': 8.9, 'Y': 5.5}, {'X': 12.9, 'Y': 2.9}], [{'X': 12.9, 'Y': 2.9}, {'X': 12.5, 'Y': 8.1}], [{'X': 12.5, 'Y': 8.1}, {'X': 8.3, 'Y': 10.9}], [{'X': 8.3, 'Y': 10.9}, {'X': 4.0, 'Y': 1.9}], [{'X': 4.0, 'Y': 1.9}, {'X': -1.1, 'Y': 12.6}], [{'X': -1.1, 'Y': 12.6}, {'X': -5.6, 'Y': 13.6}], [{'X': -5.6, 'Y': 13.6}, {'X': -9.3, 'Y': 9.3}], [{'X': -9.3, 'Y': 9.3}, {'X': -6.8, 'Y': 4.1}]
]

The ISSUE that I'm facing now is to store these monotone polygons in such a way that I can later parse upon them one by one to triangulate them my triangulation algorithm.
I tried making adjacency list for each coordinate of the polygon to look at each side of a vertex and see whether a diagonal coordinate exists, if it does then the loop terminates and all the coordinates up till that moment is appended to that sub-polygons vertex set.
The expectations of this method was to receive a list of dictionaries consisting coordinates of sub-polygons in the form of:
[
{'sub-polygon1': [{'X': value, 'Y': value}, {'X': value, 'Y': value}, {'X': value, 'Y': value}, ..]},
{'sub-polygon2': [{'X': value, 'Y': value}, {'X': value, 'Y': value}, {'X': value, 'Y': value}, ..]},
.
.
.
.
] 

But the process didn't resulted in the desired output.
Does anyone know a better way to parse through the polygon in a way that when a diagonal is encountered the algorithm exhausts all the other normal coordinates(not the diagonal coordinates) such that the sub-polygon could be detached from the former and be stored in the format as suggested above. A python implementation taking in account the instances given above would be really helpful.
